# Searching Records from gridview based on value enterd into TextBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, linq, gridview, pagination

I am trying to Search records from gridview with pagination, matching with the values entered into textbox, and its working quite fine. Issue is that it only show the records which are at first page , but not search the records from the next pages.

aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdFutureApt" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" CssClass="table table-responsive table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" AllowPaging="true" 
         CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="GrdFutureApt_PageIndexChanging">

         <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="PatientName" HeaderText="Patient Name" Visible="false"/>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="DoctorName" HeaderText="Doctor Name"/>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="AppointmentDate" HeaderText="Appointment Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"/>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Appointment Time" SortExpression="Time">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAppointmentTime" Text='<%# DisplayAs12HourTime(Eval("AppointmentTime")) %>'></asp:Label>

                  </ItemTemplate> 
               </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="AppoinmentStatus" HeaderText="Status"/>
         </Columns>
         <PagerSettings  Mode="NextPrevious" PreviousPageText="Previous" NextPageText="&nbsp; Next"  Position="Bottom" />
         <PagerStyle BackColor="#889FA2" HorizontalAlign="Left"  ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" />
     </asp:GridView>
```

I have used Following script to perform this function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=txtSearchBox.ClientID %>').keyup(function (e) {
            SearchGridData();

        });
    });
    function SearchGridData() {
        var counter = 0;
        //Get the search text
        var searchText = $('#<%=txtSearchBox.ClientID %>').val().toLowerCase();
        //Hide No record found message
        $('#<%=lblMsgFail.ClientID %>').hide();
        //Hode all the rows of gridview
        $('#<%=GrdAppointments.ClientID %> tr:has(td)').hide();
        if (searchText.length > 0) {
            //Iterate all the td of all rows
            $('#<%=GrdAppointments.ClientID %> tr:has(td)').children().each(function () {
                var cellTextValue = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                //Check that text is matches or not
                if (cellTextValue.indexOf(searchText) >= 0) {
                    $(this).parent().show();
                    counter++;
                }
            });
            if (counter == 0) {
                //Show No record found message
                $('#<%=lblErrorMsg.ClientID %>').show();
            }
        }
        else {
            //Show All the rows of gridview
            $('#<%=lblErrorMsg.ClientID %>').hide();
            $('#<%=GrdAppointments.ClientID %> tr:has(td)').show();

        }
    }
</script>
```

And using following javascript

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the data to fill gridview comes from the following function:

```
public void LoadGrid()
{
    S011AppointmentBOL objBol = new S011AppointmentBOL();
    //DataTable ptApt = new DataTable();
    dtAppointment = S011AppointmentBLL.GetAll();

    int patID = dtPatient.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("RegistrationNo") == RegNo).Select(x => x.Field<int>("PatientID")).FirstOrDefault();
    dtAppointment.Columns.Add("PatientName", typeof(string));
    dtAppointment.Columns.Add("DoctorName", typeof(string));
    for (int i = 0; i < dtAppointment.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string pFname = dtPatient.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(x => x.Field<int>("PatientID") == Convert.ToInt32(dtAppointment.Rows[i]["PatientID"]))
                        .Select(x => x.Field<string>("FirstName")).FirstOrDefault();
        string pLname = dtPatient.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(x => x.Field<int>("PatientID") == Convert.ToInt32(dtAppointment.Rows[i]["PatientID"]))
                        .Select(x => x.Field<string>("LastName")).FirstOrDefault();
        string dFname = dtDoctor.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(x => x.Field<int>("DoctorID") == Convert.ToInt32(dtAppointment.Rows[i]["DoctorID"]))
                        .Select(x => x.Field<string>("FirstName")).FirstOrDefault();
        string dLname = dtDoctor.AsEnumerable()
                         .Where(x => x.Field<int>("DoctorID") == Convert.ToInt32(dtAppointment.Rows[i]["DoctorID"]))
                         .Select(x => x.Field<string>("LastName")).FirstOrDefault();
        dtAppointment.Rows[i]["PatientName"] = pFname + " " + pLname;
        dtAppointment.Rows[i]["DoctorName"] = dFname + " " + dLname;
    }
    DataTable boundTable = new DataTable();
    var query = dtAppointment.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("PatientID") == patID).Select(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<DateTime>("AppointmentDate"));
    var t = query.Any();
    if (t)
    {
        boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
    }

    GrdAppointments.DataSource = boundTable;
    GrdAppointments.DataBind();
}
```

And On every keyup I don't want query to database that's why am using the Datatable to fill gridview
 Any Help Appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: look into jquery DataTables if it could be any use to you. very slick when used right. https://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled paging for Gridview so it will bind only records from selected pages on client side.So you have to either disable paging or rewrite jquery search function by calling a webmethord to search entire records which can bind search results.